# Russian archive of Ubuntu CDN

Tags: cdn

I'm a Ukrainian, so when I try to download update for Ubuntu (for example by Terminal) or some programs via the vanilla store, then connection gets aborted. It happens because the Ukranian goverment has passed a law that blocks the Russian node in Ubuntu CDN. What can I do to avoid it? For example, is there any way of changing my default node?

Comment: It is because of Yandex block. Yandex hosts Ubuntu repos. You can select another server in System Settings -> Software & Updates.